Connecting to a mongo db database hosted on another machine using Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow/dags/amb_tracking.py", line 24, in <module>
    for document in data:
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1243, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1160, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1039, in __send_message
    response = client._run_operation(
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/_csot.py", line 108, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1431, in _run_operation
    return self._retryable_read(
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1540, in _retryable_read
    return self._retry_internal(
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/_csot.py", line 108, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1507, in _retry_internal
    ).run()
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2353, in run
    return self._read() if self._is_read else self._write()
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2483, in _read
    self._server = self._get_server()
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2439, in _get_server
    return self._client._select_server(
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1322, in _select_server
    server = topology.select_server(
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 368, in select_server
    server = self._select_server(
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 346, in _select_server
    servers = self.select_servers(
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 253, in select_servers
    server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(
  File "/home/shoun10/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 303, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 66c757342d6ab7d2d5e58086, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>

I tried connecting to a mongo db database hosted on another machine on my local machine using pymongo and MongoClient by feeding the mongo host,port,db name and collection name however it showed me this error message.

Show us your code, please.
